# echo array null values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and I know this is an easy one but still can't find a solution.

I have an array that holds 4 different images and I want to echo the results
so my HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $results['image1']?>" >
<img src="<?php echo $results['image2']?>" >
<img src="<?php echo $results['image3']?>" >
<img src="<?php echo $results['image4']?>" >
```

But what if for example image4 is null? - i don't want to echo the whole 
    `<img src>` tag line

How can i do it?
Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your work around example.

```
<?php
if(!empty($results['image1'])) echo '<img src="'.$results['image1'].'">';
if(!empty($results['image2'])) echo '<img src="'.$results['image2'].'">';
if(!empty($results['image3'])) echo '<img src="'.$results['image3'].'">';
if(!empty($results['image4'])) echo '<img src="'.$results['image4'].'">';
?>
```

try this code may it helps you. here i have check first if result not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($results['image1']) && !empty($results['image1'])){ ?><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($results['image1']}; ?>" ><?php } ?>
<?php if(isset($results['image2']) && !empty($results['image2'])){ ?><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($results['image2']}; ?>" ><?php } ?>
<?php if(isset($results['image3']) && !empty($results['image3'])){ ?><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($results['image3']}; ?>" ><?php } ?>
<?php if(isset($results['image4']) && !empty($results['image4'])){ ?><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($results['image4']}; ?>" ><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?if(isset($results['image1']) && $results['image1'] != ""){?><img src="<?=$results['image1']?>" ><?}?>
```

With this you check it the image is set. Do that for each of your images and you should be fine.
The `isset` is not necessary, but some setups of php throw a warning without it. Thus it's better practice to use it.

If you don't want all the short-tags, do it like this:

```
if(isset($results['image1']) && $results['image1'] != ""){echo "<img src='{$results['image1']}' >"; }
```

That should be about the fanciest you can do. the `"x{$variable}y"` works like  `"x".$variable."y"` but is easier to write/read, if you like it.